# RabbitMQ: password protected queues

Tags: rabbitmq

I'd like to bind single queue to single user. Also I'd like to make all queues private with their own username/password. Rabbit should get credentials from database.
Can someone point me the way how to organize such security.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean for "user" ? 
Application user or Software user?

I think your software have to manage the security, but you can see the RabbitMQ virtual host, for each virtual host you can define different user name and password.

Read here:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html

and [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmqctl.1.man.html) section virtual host.

Read also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840283/how-can-queues-be-made-private-secure-in-rabbitmq-in-a-multitenancy-system)